# MultinomialNB fails with "ValueError: shapes not aligned" during prediction phase

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, naivebayes, multinomial

I am trying to do a MultinomialNB(). I have a csv, that I read into a dataframe (data) and did some tokenizing and lemmatization on the data in order to have the most used words. The code for the model is this:

```
max_features = 5000
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=max_features , stop_words= "english") 
sparce_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(Tweet_list).toarray()
y = data.iloc[:,0].values
x = sparce_matrix

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.1)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

Mn = MultinomialNB()
Mn.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = Mn.predict(x_test)
print("Accuracy: ", Mn.score(y_pred.reshape(-1,1),y_test))
```

When i print the sizes of the variables:

```
print(y.size)
print(x.size)
print(x_train.size)
print(y_train.size)
print(x_test.size)
print("y test", y_test.size)
print("y pred", y_pred.size)
```

I get:

```
86460
432300000
389070000
77814
43230000
y test 8646
y pred 8646
```

However the model fails with ValueError: shapes (8646,1) and (5000,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5000 (dim 0).

As far as I understand the problem is somewhere in the computation it does behind the methods where some np.dot(a, b) fails. It somehow computes the y_pred or y_test (8646) with a vector of the size of max features vector (5000). That is the only place where the value 5000 appears.

Comment: Can you print out shape instead of size? Also, at which line is the error occuring?

Comment: y (86460,)
x (86460, 5000)
x_train (77814, 5000)
y_train (77814,)
x_test (8646, 5000)
y_test (8646,)
y_pred (8646,)  These are the shapes. Also the error was in the last line, print("Accuracy: ", Mn.score(y_pred.reshape(-1,1),y_test))

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the documentation of [MultinomialNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.score), you can see that the first input to the score function is NOT `y_pred` but `X`. Hence, the call to the score function should be,

```
print("Accuracy: ", Mn.score(x_test,y_test))
```

`self.predict(x_test)` will get automatically called inside the function `score`.

Documentation should always be the first method of debugging your code.